# php deleting a specific folder and all its contents

Tags: php, recursion, directory

I'm using php to delete folders containing images of posts that where deleted. I'm using the code below which I found online and does a good job.

I want to know how can I delete only a specific folder in a folder when there are other folders in it.

When I using the code below, how is it possible to do this?
Using: /dev/images/norman/8 -> Will not delete folder 8
Using: /dev/images/norman/ -> Will delete all folders

```
Eg:
/dev/images/norman/8 -> I need to delete only this folder
/dev/images/norman/9
/dev/images/norman/10
/dev/images/norman/11
/dev/images/norman/12

<?php
$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/dev/images/norman/8';

emptyDir($path);

function emptyDir($path) { 

    // INITIALIZE THE DEBUG STRING
    $debugStr  = '';
    $debugStr .= "Deleting Contents Of: $path<br /><br />";

    // PARSE THE FOLDER
    if ($handle = opendir($path)) {

        while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {

            if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {

                // IF IT"S A FILE THEN DELETE IT
                if(is_file($path."/".$file)) {

                    if(unlink($path."/".$file)) {
                    $debugStr .= "Deleted File: ".$file."<br />";   
                    }

                } else {

                    // IT IS A DIRECTORY
                    // CRAWL THROUGH THE DIRECTORY AND DELETE IT'S CONTENTS

                    if($handle2 = opendir($path."/".$file)) {

                        while (false !== ($file2 = readdir($handle2))) {

                            if ($file2 != "." && $file2 != "..") {
                                if(unlink($path."/".$file."/".$file2)) {
                                $debugStr .= "Deleted File: $file/$file2<br />";    
                                }
                            }

                        }

                    }

                    if(rmdir($path."/".$file)) {
                    $debugStr .= "Directory: ".$file."<br />";  
                    }

                }

            }

        }

    }
    echo $debugStr;
}

?>
```

Comment: @FirmView This is delete everything under folder 8 but not the folder 8

Comment: have you tried the solution i posted?

Comment: Yes, I ran that and it works really well. Hang on a sec.

Comment: if my answer is correct, then you can check it as right answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<?php

delete_directory($dirname) {
   if (is_dir($dirname))
      $dir_handle = opendir($dirname);
   if (!$dir_handle)
      return false;
   while($file = readdir($dir_handle)) {
      if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {
         if (!is_dir($dirname."/".$file))
            unlink($dirname."/".$file);
         else
            delete_directory($dirname.'/'.$file);    
      }
   }
   closedir($dir_handle);
   rmdir($dirname);
   return true;
 }
?>
```

if you are using, version 5.1 and above,

```
<?php
function deleteDir($dir) {
   $iterator = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($dir);
   foreach (new RecursiveIteratorIterator($iterator, RecursiveIteratorIterator::CHILD_FIRST) as $file) 
   {
      if ($file->isDir()) {
         rmdir($file->getPathname());
      } else {
         unlink($file->getPathname());
      }
   }
   rmdir($dir);
}

deleteDir("temporary");
?>
```

Comment: first all the contents of the folder will get deleted.  At the end, the folder will get deleted.

Answer (score 2):

You want to hear about [`rmdir`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rmdir.php).

```
if(is_file($path."/".$file)) {

    if(unlink($path."/".$file)) {
    $debugStr .= "Deleted File: ".$file."<br />";   
    }

} else {

    if(rmdir($path."/".$file)) {
        $debugStr .= "Deleted Directory: ".$file."<br />";   
    }

}
```

EDIT: as `rmdir` can only handle empty dirs, you may use this solution as reported in rmdir's page comments:

```
function rrmdir($dir) {
    foreach(glob($dir . '/*') as $file) {
        if(is_dir($file))
            rrmdir($file);
        else
            unlink($file);
    }
    rmdir($dir);
}
```

It just recursively deletes everything in `$dir`, then gets rid of directory itself.

Comment: rmdir can delete only empty directories.

Comment: @S3Mi my bad, I will provide a recursive solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use system commands ex. `exec("rm -rf {$dirPath}");` or if you want to do it by PHP you have to go recursive, loops won't do it right.

```
public function deleteDir($path) {

    if ($handle = opendir($path)) {

        while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {

            if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {

                // IF IT"S A FILE THEN DELETE IT
                if(is_file($path."/".$file)) {

                    if(unlink($path."/".$file)) {
                        $debugStr .= "Deleted File: ".$file."<br />";
                    }

                } else {
                    deleteDir($path."/".$file."/");
                    rmdir($path."/".$file);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> When I using the code below, how is it possible to do this? Using:
>   /dev/images/norman/8 -> Will not delete folder 8 Using:
>   /dev/images/norman/ -> Will delete all folders

I think your problem is that you're missing "/" at the end of "/dev/images/norman/8"

Answer (score 0):

I added an `$exclude` param to your function, this param it's an array with the names of directories you want to exclude from being deleted, like so:

```
$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/dev/images/norman/';

emptyDir($path); //will delete all under /norman/
emptyDir($path, array('8')); //will delete all under /norman/ except dir 8
emptyDir($path, array('8','10')); //will delete all under /norman/ except dir 8 and 10

function emptyDir($path,$exclude=false) { 

    // INITIALIZE THE DEBUG STRING
    $debugStr  = '';
    $debugStr .= "Deleting Contents Of: $path<br /><br />";
    if (!$exclude) {
       $exclude = array();
    }

    // PARSE THE FOLDER
    if ($handle = opendir($path)) {

        while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {

            if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {

                // IF IT"S A FILE THEN DELETE IT
                if(is_file($path."/".$file)) {

                    if(unlink($path."/".$file)) {
                    $debugStr .= "Deleted File: ".$file."<br />";   
                    }

                } else if (!in_array($file, $exclude)) {

                    // IT IS A DIRECTORY
                    // CRAWL THROUGH THE DIRECTORY AND DELETE IT'S CONTENTS

                    if($handle2 = opendir($path."/".$file)) {

                        while (false !== ($file2 = readdir($handle2))) {

                            if ($file2 != "." && $file2 != "..") {
                                if(unlink($path."/".$file."/".$file2)) {
                                $debugStr .= "Deleted File: $file/$file2<br />";    
                                }
                            }

                        }

                    }

                    if(rmdir($path."/".$file)) {
                    $debugStr .= "Directory: ".$file."<br />";  
                    }

                }

            }

        }

    }
    echo $debugStr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$path='./ggg';
rrmdir($path);
function rrmdir($dir) {
if (is_dir($dir)) {
 $objects = scandir($dir);
 foreach ($objects as $object) {
   if ($object != "." && $object != "..") {
     if (filetype($dir."/".$object) == "dir") rrmdir($dir."/".$object); else unlink($dir."/".$object);
   }
 }
 reset($objects);
 rmdir($dir);
}
}
```