# Wordpress: delete folder via action hook

Tags: wordpress, filesystems, directory

I have a function that's doing something awesome, and when this finishes the work it should delete a folder and it's not. Here's what and how:

This is where I hook my function and it works

```
 add_action('option_after_ajax_save', 'run_custom_function');
```

This is where I have my function

```
function run_custom_function() {
    global $wp_rewrite, $wp_filesystem;
    $my_folder = ABSPATH . 'wp-content/themes/' . $themename . '/inc/my-folder/';
    //other code
    //now once everything else is done and everything works to this point, delete the folder
    unlink($my_folder); // I also tried rmdir($my_folder); and it's not working
}
```

Do you have any idea?

Comment: try using [realpath](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php)

Comment: Thanks but it's not working, perhaps because my function runs in AJAX, not sure have to check.

Comment: Have you checked the value of `$my_folder ` ? The path may be wrong

Comment: Have you checked the folder is empty? You can't delete a folder with files in it. Have you considered swapping unlink with a function that can recursively delete files/folders inside the given path?

Comment: I think what Nathan said could be the right thing, let me check if that is the case.

Comment: I solved this one, Nathan your idea worked, I found this code here
http://stackoverflow.com/a/12621934/803358

Too bad I didn't have a back-up :D